Websocket connection failed, if client not placed inside html
I'm trying to setup a WebSocket between an ESP32-S3 board and a web navigator (Firefox)
My firmware has a web server, WebSocket server and also embed a web client written in HTML, CSS, JS, based on esp-idf.
My web client is placed in a JS file
function startWebSocketConnection() {   
    socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.4.1/ws");

In this configuration, the client fails to open a connection to the websocket server.
But, when placed inside the html file it works
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.4.1/ws");

    socket.onopen = function () {
        socket.send("Hello Server!");
    };


Try to connect to my websocket. It does not open a connection if JS code is not placed in the HTML part.

You need to add details to your question if you want someone to be able to help-- it's the browser that can't connect to the server?  What is the file structure like on the browser?  If your JS is not in the HTML page that's rendered by the browser, it's not going to do anything
